# Month Year format on a datepicker with range select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So, I'm trying to follow the example given in the JQuery's datepicker for the range option, shown here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range (I'll post code below in case page changes.)

What I'm trying to do is format the input field so that it shows "MM yy". But when I change the line `var dateFormat = "MM yy",` or when I add `formatDate: "MM yy"` in the datepicker section, the date picker allows the To field to select a date previous to the From date.  Essentially, what I'm trying to do is create a ranged month picker.

Jquery's Range picker example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 3
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm really close to what I want with the following. The final problem is I can't hide the calendar so that the user can only choose the month and year. But I can live with this if there is no answer.

```
<div class="input-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <label class="pr-3 font-weight-bold" for="fromDate">Start Date:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" autocomplete="off"
               class="form-control ui-monthpicker col-6" aria-label="from-date"
               aria-describedby="from-date" data-date-format="mm-yyyy"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <label class="pr-3 font-weight-bold" for="toDate">End Date:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" autocomplete="off"
               class="form-control ui-monthpicker col-6" aria-label="to-date"
               aria-describedby="to-date" data-date-format="mm-yyyy"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var monthNumber = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; ++i) {
        monthNumber[monthNames[i]] = i;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.ui-monthpicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: "+0D",
            dateFormat: 'MM yy'
        });

        $('#fromDate').datepicker('option', 'onClose', function (datePicker) {
            $(this).val(datePicker);
            let start = datePicker.split(' ');
            $('#toDate').datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(start[1], monthNumber[start[0]]));
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some more digging, I've got my answer (Java/Springboot/Thy:

```
<div class="input-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <label class="pr-3 font-weight-bold" for="fromDate">Start Date:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input id="fromDate" type="text" th:field="*{fromDate}" autocomplete="off"
               class="form-control ui-monthpicker col-6"
               aria-label="from-date" aria-describedby="from-date"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <label class="pr-3 font-weight-bold" for="toDate">End Date:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input id="toDate" type="text" th:field="*{toDate}" autocomplete="off"
               class="form-control ui-monthpicker col-6"
               aria-label="to-date" aria-describedby="to-date"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    let monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var monthNumber = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; ++i) {
        monthNumber[monthNames[i]] = i;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.ui-monthpicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: "+0D",
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            beforeShow: function() {
                if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0)
                {
                    iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                    iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
                            $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                }
            },
            onClose: function() {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                // If they don't like the long month format, change the line below to 'M yy'
                $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));

                if ($(this).attr("id") == "fromDate") {
                    let fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
                    let start = fromDate.split(' ');
                    $('#toDate').datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(start[1], monthNumber[start[0]]));
                }
            }
        });
        $('.ui-monthpicker').datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(2006, 6));

</script>
<style>
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```